# Nearest value iteration

Tags: python, pandas

```
s1 = pd.Series({11:100, 13:102, 17:99})
s2 = pd.Series({10:1, 14:2, 18:3})
```

Having these series, individually I can find s2's value by the nearest index of s2, using s1's index. Example:

`s2.values[np.abs(s2.index - s1.index[0]).argmin()]`

Returns 1 because 11, s1's first index is closest to 10.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to create a DataFrame that has s1 and these values iterated, without using a for loop which I've been been taught is unpractical in pandas.

So the desired outcome is a DataFrame with s1's values in one column and the other having s2's value using the code above.

Comment: You should go with root's answer. In case you are still curious on how to vectorize the code, though, you could do somthing like `df['s2_nearest'] = s1.index` and then `df['s2_nearest'].map(lambda i:s2.values[np.abs(s2.index - i).argmin()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) on `s2` with `method='nearest'`:

```
s2 = s2.reindex(s1.index, method='nearest')
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1': s1, 's2': s2})
```

The resulting output:

```
     s1  s2
11  100   1
13  102   2
17   99   3
```